# Load Single HTML Element in WKWebView

Tags: html, ios, swift

I'm able to get the HTML from a URL and load it in a WKWebView, but I'm wanting to just load a single element from the HTML. In this case, that element is an aside, `<aside class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar">`

My code for getting all of the HTML.

```
func getHTMLString() -> String? {

        let urlString = "https://kyfb.com/\(county)"

        guard let countyUrl = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return nil
        }

        do {
            let htmlString = try String(contentsOf: countyUrl, encoding: .isoLatin1)
            return htmlString
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

The specific URL I'm trying is https://kyfb.com/jefferson. There is an aside there that has everything I'm wanting to show.

Comment: Link doesn't seem to be working. Also, an "aside", and what is your specific problem?

Comment: The link works for me. The aside in the HTML is <aside class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar">. I only want to display the contents of that particular element from the HTML.

Comment: Link works fine here. Is your question how to extract an element from the DOM ? First you need to use an HTML parser (or regex) and then load it using your `WKWebView`

Comment: @nathan Yes, I want to extract an element from the DOM and load it in the WKWebView

Comment: The problem is keeping the defined styles. Extracting the element is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the element from the HTML code you downloaded is easy:

```
    guard let html = getHTML()
        else { return }

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<aside class=\"col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar\">([\\s\\S]*)</aside>")
    let match = regex
        .matches(in: html, range: NSRange(html.startIndex..., in: html))
        .map {
            html.substring(with: Range($0.range, in: html)!)
    }

    self.webView.loadHTMLString(match.first!, baseURL: nil)
```

The problem is that CSS/JS won't be captured. Another solution would be injecting Javascript and hiding every element except `<aside></aside>`

Comment: Still saving lives! :D